# How is the "precision matrix" derived from the covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, descriptive-statistics

The probability density function (PDF) of a Gaussian (or Normal) distribution centred on the origin in n-dimensional space is given by : p($x$) = B exp[$-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Lambda x$], where $x = (x_1, ... , x_n)$ and $\Lambda$ is an $n$ X $n$ matrix known as the "precision matrix" and B is just a normalising factor.

I understand that the covariance matrix is essentially a measure of how different variables "co-vary" and correlate with one another, but what does the "precision matrix" here mean? Is it a measure of how "co-concentrated" variables are? Furthermore, how would one even arrive to the expression given above... what is the motivation?

Comment: Precision matrix here is the inverse of covariance matrix.

Comment: ... in the same way that for a 1-D random variable, the inverse of variance is called "precision" suggesting that more precision suggests less dispersion.  The motivation is to reduce the number of times you need to invert the variance matrix.  For example with conjugate families of distributions, using precision can allow use of Gamma or Wishart priors rather than more obscure distributions

Comment: Okay, and is the reason why we have $\Lambda$ in our quadratic form when calculating probabilities because the more "concentrated" things are (at for example the origin), the higher the probability of then finding them there? Also, is $\Lambda$ the direct inverse of the Covariance matrix?